# support vector machines - solving for alphas

Tags: machine-learning, svm

In Svm, this is our dual problem optimization objective with the following constrains along with alphas between 0 and C. How do i find alphas with this optimization objective and these constrians.
[image]

Also, please correct me, if i am wrong somewhere

Comment: What do you exactly want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you want to maximize the Lagrangean of this optimization problem, right?

So what you did was to set the partial derivatives of your relevant components to zero to build the Lagrangean. You did that because in the optimum, they are equal to zero. This is the necessary condition to find a stationary point but because of the convexity property of your original problem this is also the optimal solution.

To maximize over the alphas, you want to use the SMO algorithm as described here:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_minimal_optimization

Good luck!